# Trying to get information from database

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to get information about `cost` in database `items` by `name` and img getting error `Resource id #5`

My database looks like:
[image]

My set.php

```
<?php
$sitename = "localhost";
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('csgo', $link);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

function fetchinfo($rowname,$tablename,$finder,$findervalue) {
    if($finder == "1") $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename");
    else $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename WHERE `$finder`='$findervalue'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row[$rowname];
}
?>
```

And my code to get cost

```
<?php
$item = $_GET['item'];
$item = str_replace("\"", "", $item);
$item = str_replace("\'", "", $item);
$item = str_replace(" ", "%20", $item);
$item = str_replace("\\", "", $item);



@include_once ("set.php");

$item_cost = mysql_query("SELECT cost FROM items WHERE name='$item'");



echo $item_cost;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, stop using `mysql_*` and start using `mysqli_*`, check the warning at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Check this tutorial http://codular.com/php-mysqli

`Resource id #5` is not an error, the `mysql_query` function doesn't directly return the output of the SQL Query, it returns an object that you should loop on, for example

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `live` = 1';

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['username'] . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to echo the result resource of the executed sql query.

You have pass this resource e.g. to mysql_fetch_array() and then can loop over that array (see http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-query.php)